# Retrieving location updates in the background and send data on iOS

Tags: ios, background, core-location, location-services

I am trying to get the users' location updates and send it to the server every 1 minute in the background in iOS.

The app needs to keep track of the driver’s position continuously similar to Uber and report it to our server every minute.

I tried background fetch and background locations and it runs fine for 3 minutes and then stops.

How do we accomplish this? Please advise.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: downvoted as this was asked a lot previously. The related tags provide all you need :P

Comment: not closing cause questions are old (still valid) but old ^^

Answer (score -1):

you cant accomplish exactly that, since An app cannot just run in the BG for a continous interval. (Exception for Bluetooth (sometimes) and Audio or VOIP

#### look for another way to do it:

==> besides background refresh, def. look at significant location updates (!) [[Getting user location when app is in background. IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30940451/getting-user-location-when-app-is-in-background-ios?rq=1])